# An existing connection was forcibly closed by the remote host python django app for json

Tags: python, json

Ok , I have a json url, If I go directly to that url on my browser i get a page with some information in json format. I want this information to be fetched in my python code in objects.

```
  {
    "count": 2, 
    "list": [
        {
            "family_name": "xxx", 
            "display_name": "xxx", 
            "name": "xxx", 
            "locality": "xxx", 
        }, 
        {
            "family_name": "yyy", 
            "display_name": "yyy", 
            "name": "yyy", 
            "locality": "yyy", 
        }
    ]
}
```

So this is what I did:

```
import urllib2
import json

response = urllib2.urlopen('https://xxx.xxx.xxx/jsonfiles/xxxxxxxx.json')
data = json.load(response)
```

but it is throwing error at 3rd line, An existing connection was forcibly closed by the remote host python.

Comment: gone through that, but couldnt find out whats the issue.

Comment: here is the url: https://expert.gwu.edu/jsonfiles/de455afa245cf8371e466d449d3166e9.json

Comment: how can we get data from external domains ?